# What happened in the Gamma Forest?

Tags: doctor-who

In *A Good Man Goes to War* we meet Lorna Bucket, who is from the Gamma Forest. Throughout the episode we learn that The Doctor had some sort of an adventure in the Gamma Forest the result of which was:

1. The Gamma Forest became neutral.
2. Doctor came to mean a mighty warrior, in the language of the forest.

Does anyone know what happened there. Is it a story in any form (written, audiobook, comic) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we do know what happened in the [Doctor Who annual 2013](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Lorna%27s_Escape_%28short_story%29) there was a story called Lorna's escape saying about what happened in the Gamma Forests :)

Comment: And? What happened?

Answer (score 8):

The Gamma Forest story is from a period in the current Doctor's future but from the point of view of Lorna Bucket, her past. There is no current literature detailing events from the Gamma Forest.

> When Lorna Bucket was a child, she met the Doctor in the Gamma Forests. She recalled that he repeatedly told her to "run". She also claimed that the reason she enlisted in the Church was partly because the Doctor's short visit to the forests was the only thing that had ever happened there. Lorna later crafted a prayer leaf and gave it to Amy Pond, who had recently been separated from her newborn daughter. Later as Lorna died, the Doctor pretended to recall their adventure there, despite the fact he had not yet met Lorna in his own timeline. (DW: A Good Man Goes to War) - [Tardis Index Wikia > Gamma Forest](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Gamma_Forests)

Comment: Did it really not happen in his timeline? Or did he just forget about her? The way I saw it, they wanted to characterize him as ruthless in that episode and that he uses those who love and trust him for his own good. So it would fit that he doesn't remember Lorna after doing whatever warrior-stuff he did with her in the Gamma Forests

Comment: No, it has not happened yet to him. Being able to move forward and backward through time, at some point in the future, he will meet this young woman. But for her it will be in the past from the perspective of that particular episode. So he could not have met her at the moment and still eventually experience the event. The difference is now, having met her and seen her die, he may remember her when he sees her in HIS future, from his perspective. Which will make meeting her even sadder, to him.

Comment: Was it said in the episode that in his timeline the gamma forest events are in the future? I see that this is mentioned in the wiki article that you quote, but I can't remember that from the episode, I think I have to rewatch it. I always thought that he had already visited the gamma forest before (in his own timeline).

Comment: Remember the first rule of the Doctor: The Doctor lies. He lied to the young woman about remembering her to ease her passing. It is clearly seen in his face he is lying and he is distraught that he does not know her.

Comment: @Thaddeus And after she passes away, The Doctor asks who she was.

Comment: You shouldn't always trust the TARDIS wikia, sometimes it contains little errors or things which are debatable interpretations of one editor...if you look at the relevant section of the [transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/32-7.htm) of "A Good Man Goes To War", there's really nothing in the dialogue to tell us if he doesn't remember her because it hasn't happened yet, or if it's just an adventure in his past that he forgot about.